# xdotool doesn't work via SSH

Tags: ssh, xdotool

I want to use xdotool via SSH but get the following error:

```
Error: Can't open display: (default)
```

I found this solution:

```
export DISPLAY='0:0'
```

Still get nearly the same error :(. I also tried:

```
export DISPLAY=:0; or: export DISPLAY="0:0", ...
```

Always a error like that:

```
Error: Can't open display: (0:0)
```

Is thera a alternative (working) solution for xdotool?

I don' know whether It work lokal. I've only got a SSH-connection.

Comment: How is SSH involved here? Are you trying to use SSH's X forwarding feature? How did you run ssh to log into the server where you're trying to run xdotool?

Answer (score 10):

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xdotool key a
```

Try this =)

Answer (score 5):

You did the right thing `export DISPLAY='0:0'`

But you should also set **XAUTHORITY** like this:

`export XAUTHORITY="/home/username/.Xauthority"`

Ofcourse the username is an account which has logged in via gnome.

> Don't forget to change username with your right account name.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26841554/2777965) answer worked. Perhaps you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -2):

I have found a useful link for this problem please refer the below post
[Accessing the X Display for Ubuntu GDM login screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719987/accessing-the-x-display-for-ubuntu-gdm-login-screen)

It says

> "You need authority to connect to the display. Note the -auth parameter to the X command. That's where the authority is."

try with

```
export XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-[whatever-it-is]/database
```

Hope it helps